# How to connect spring application on docker to a cluster of activemq on docker

Tags: spring, rest, docker, activemq-classic

I have a simple REST application running on Tomcat8 in a docker container. I also have 3 docker containers running ActiveMQ 5.11.1 broker in master slave (with mysql as persistence) on ports `61616`, `61617` and `61618` respectively.

```
docker run --name myRESTApp -t -i --rm -p 8080:8080 -p 9090:9090  -v $(pwd)/webapps:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps -v $(pwd)/logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs --link activemq1:activemq myRESTApp
```

In myRESTApp's `activeMQConfiguration.xml`:

```
<property name="brokerURL" value="failover:(#{systemEnvironment['ACTIVEMQ_PORT_61616_TCP']})?randomize=false"/>
```

The 3 ActiveMQ brokers has this in their `activemq.xml`:

```
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:0" updateClusterClients="true" rebalanceClusterClients="true" updateClusterClientsOnRemove="true" />
</transportConnectors>
```

The master initially was running on `61616`, I stopped the master, slave (port `61617`) became the new master.

Even before the master on `61616` was stopped, it threw

```
Connect fail to: tcp://172.17.0.84:61616, reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Why after linking, it still unable to connect to the broker?

After the master on `61616` is stopped, it is failing with:

```
Connect fail to: tcp://172.17.0.84:61616, reason: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

Shouldn't it auto update the client of the new master like what being mentioned [here](http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.sg/2010/10/new-features-in-activemq-54-automatic.html)?

Can anyone please advise what is the best practise for connecting the ActiveMQ cluster of broker to my application? Thanks

Comment: Wrote a simple client to test the ActiveMQ broker (something like HelloWorldProducer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480023/activemq-and-embedded-broker), corrected the uri in transportConnector to tcp://0.0.0.0:61616 now able to post a test message to the Queue. However, it still does not able update client of the new Master